# get multi select listbox values to spring controller through ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have a multi select list box. I want to send the user selected list box values to the spring controller. I'm making a ajax call to perform action.
Please suggest through ajax call how can i send all the values from the multi selected list box to java spring controller and get all selected list box values. Please find the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bwc3yqme/5/.

Below is my ajax call:

```
function updatedInfo()
{
    var xmlHttp;  
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    var url = contextPath+"/updateInfo.htm";
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        handleServerResponse(xmlHttp);
    };
    xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);

    function handleServerResponse(xmlHttp)
    {   
       if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
       {


       }   
    }
}
```

controller:

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/updateInfo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public void updateInfo(HttpServletRequest request,
           HttpServletResponse response, @ModelAttribute MyDataDTO myDto,BindingResult beException,final @RequestParam("selItems") String params){

//i want to get the user selected list box values...

}
```

Please suggest how can i send user selected list box values through ajax to spring controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all values from the right side listbox with JQuery inside your `updateInfo` function:

```
var params = "?";
var andParam = "";
$("#d option").each(function(){
    params += andParam + "selected=" + $(this).val();
    andParam = "&";
});
```

Add it as parameters to your url like this:

```
var url = contextPath+"/updateInfo.htm"+params;
```

And then read it from request (it will be an array):

```
request.getParameter("selected");
```

**Edited [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fbvu3g03/1)**

Comment: When i kept the code in above ajax function its throwing javascript error, unexpected identifier. Please suggest where to keep the code $("#d option:selected").each(function(){ .. Thanks. @jmartins

Comment: Inside the updatedInfo function. When do you call it (updatedInfo) exactly?

Comment: I missed a "+" between strings, my bad.

Comment: Thanks @jmartins, but issue is its only getting the highlighted elements in the selected list box. U can see the same scenario in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bwc3yqme/6/ . Which ever items i have selected from left side list box is displayed in right hand list box as selected items and only those  items are sent. But i want to send all the existing items in the right hand side list box. Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: See if is sth like that you want.

Comment: Thanks, it worked :). Please update the answer if possible so that i can accept. But one more issue i'm noticing is at spring controller its only showing first item value.But in javascript when i do alert its showing all values in the selected multi select list box. Please see the spring controller code in the original question posted. Pelase suggest if u have any idea why at spring controller only first value is seen not all the selected elements. https://jsfiddle.net/fbvu3g03/1/  thanks @jmartins

Comment: Did you use the params as "selItems" instead of "selected"?

Comment: I think you can add a different question for this case. It would be more appropriate.

Comment: I've edited the answer. If you could accept it, would be nice :)

Comment: Accepted. its my fault, got it..i have not used the same name..its working now :). Thanks a lot. Appreciate your patience. @jmartins